# how to use rest api with curl and c++ in xcode

Tags: c++, rest, post, curl

I'm trying to POST the simple data to the Parse server using REST, but not able to do so, here is the code

```
#include<curl/curl.h>

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

what is X here? do we need to define x? what connection settings need to be used to post the data successfully? and where is the return object is Json, where is is stored?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a terminal command in C++, this won't work. X is a command line option for curl.

Below is a basic example of an HTTP POST request submitted with Curl using C. You should be able to adapt this to your needs.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html